# ATS override on myAppName-Info.plist not working as expected

Tags: ios9, xcode7, info.plist, app-transport-security

I've reopened an old app I've made two years ago (on XCode 5.X or 6.X, I think, I don't remember), since the end customer is asking me to change some logos in the app.
After editing the app, I did the rebuild>run sequence, and then I get the well-known "App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP blah blah..." error.
As explained on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http), I need to add an override on the myAppName-info.plist file, via property editor (or other).
Since I already did this override on some other apps, I expected to get the app running without the ATS error, but I kept on getting it.
So, after several and various attempts, I've tried to completely remove the "myAppName-info.plist" file from the project, expecting to see some big red exclamation point on the build phase. Nothing. All runs smoothly.
Also (before deleting the .plist file), I tried to add some typo error on these fields (eg. writing "App Transport Security Settini") but again I didn't get errors.

So the question is: why this behavior ? What am I doing wrong?
Has this thing to do with the fact that now the new apps only have the file "info.plist" and no longer the file "myAppName-info.plist"?

Comment: You have to  add "myAppName-info.plist" in Build Settings> Prefix Header to inform compiler that you have added an plist file named this and that can be found on that particular path.

Comment: The right sequence is  "Build Settings > Packaging > Info.plist file" (since Prefix Header is in Apple LLVM settings). Anyway, thank you a lot for aiming me in the right direction, my path was wrong.